# LookupOrderedRows with variable WHERE clauses

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

As the title suggests is it possible to run `LookupOrderedRows` with a @variable in the WHERE clause.

```
SET @getAccounts = LookupOrderedRows(@AccountDE, 25, @orderByClause, "location_id", @AccountLocationId,"column1","true","column2","false")
```

I have a requirement where the field matches need to be dynamic, and may not be a fixed number of columns to do the match on. Has anyone got a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try leveraging the [TreatAsContent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/treatascontent.htm) function:

```
%%[
/*
declarations for @AccountLocationId, @AccountDE, @orderByClause, etc...
*/

set @test = 1

if (@test == 1) then
  set @whereClause = Concat('"location_id", "', @AccountLocationId, '", "column1", "true"')
elseif (@test == 2) then
  set @whereClause = Concat('"location_id", "', @AccountLocationId, '", "column2", "false"')
elseif (@test == 3) then
  set @whereClause = Concat('"column1", "true", "column2", "false"')
elseif (@test == 4) then
  set @whereClause = Concat('"location_id", "', @AccountLocationId, '", "column1", "true", "column2", "false"')
/* etc... */
endif
]%%
%%=TreatAsContent(Concat("%", "%[set @getAccounts = LookupOrderedRows(@AccountDE,25,@orderByClause,", @whereClause, ")]%", "%"))=%%
%%[
Output(Concat('Where Clause: (', @whereClause, ')<br>'))
Output(Concat('Row Count: ', RowCount(@getAccounts)))
]%%
```